# How to get MP3 duration using MultiPlayer of aacdecoder library in Android

Tags: android, mp3, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, aac

I am developing an android application that contains aac Mp3 Streaming. I am trying multiPlayer using aacdecoder library. Everything works well but i don't know how to take the total duration of an mp3. With MediaPlayer of android i used mediaPlayer.getDuration() but for decoding reasons i have to use a third-part library. Anyone knows if there is a way to take the total duration using MultiPlayer?

Comment: AAC or MP3?  Those are two different things.

Comment: MP3 ... but using aacdecoder library.

Comment: Hi Simas, I am also trying to play the MP3 and AAC Streaming in android.
How do you get the MultiPlayer duration?